# Error: Could not find or load main class org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher osx jenkins slave

Tags: macos, jenkins, ant, jenkins-agent

I have tried to build on Jenkins slave with osx on it and got this error. When I log into machine, I can run `ant -version` and it works. Only when I try to build from Jenkins this error occurs:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher
```

Answer (score 1):

I have found that the problems lies within brew version of ant. If i have installed separate version it works. I have found that it may be caused by different dir structure. In Brew version there is a libexec dir whether in "ordinary" there is a lib dir. Maybe creating symlink to libexec with lib name it would work but i haven't checked it.